# XSL Transformation in Silverlight

Tags: .net, xml, silverlight, xslt

Is there a way to do in Silverlight what `XslCompiledTransform` does in full .NET?
The System.Xml.Xsl namespace is obviously not complete in SL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplistic answer is: no.  Its also difficult to conceive a reason why you would want to but I'm sure you must have one.

If you really do need to use existing XSL tranforms on XML **and** your silverlight app is designed to run in-browser then you can enlist the host browsers help in performing a transform.

For example, for IE you can use:-

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Eval(@ "function transform(xml, xsl)
 {
     var xmlDOM = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0");
     xmlDOM.LoadXML(xml);
     var xslDOM = new ActiveObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0");
     xslDOM.LoadXML(xsl);

     return xmlDOM.transformNode(xslDOM);
 }");
```

Now given two strings, the xml and the xsl you use:-

```
 string result = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("transform", xmlString, xslString) as string;
```

Of course to make this cross browser you will need to detect the browser and inject the correct code to the transform function.  Some browsers will make you jump through more hoops than others but it can be done.

Comment: @_AnthonyWJones: It might be of interest to the OP and the general public to show a similar way to work with Saxon CE and use XSLT 2.0. And just to know that such thing is possible. :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Is there a "Saxon CE" library for Silverlight.  There doesn't appear to be.  If there were a way to deliver the some other XSLT processor as part of a Silverlight XAP that would be of interest in the context of this question but I don't think there is.

Comment: @_AnthonyWJones: I thought that you can use any Javascript code that IE understands. If so, it should be possible to initiate SaxonCE. @Michael Kay is the authoritative person on anything Saxon -- of course.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: My point was that in order to be able to use SaxonCE even from Javascript in IE it will need to have been installed first would it not?  This is outside of what Silverlight can control.  The choice to install it would have to be done by the user and done before anything can make use of it.

Comment: @_AnthonyWJones: AFAIK it is downloaded (taking considerable time -- 900KB) by IE the 1st time it is referenced and then it is cached and accessed instantaneously. My guess is that we'd not have to wait too long to see at least some of the 5 major browsers incorporate Saxon CE in their standard installation options.

Comment: Enlighten me please about what exactly Saxon CE is? :) (btw, AnthonyWJones was correct in assuming that I shouldn't need XSLT in SL, so I redesigned some stuff, so I'm only out to learn new stuff now)

Comment: Saxon-CE is an XSLT 2.0 processor with interactive-browser extensions, it's implemented in JavaScript and downloaded when the web page first loads - so it must be present (there's no installation) on the website host server. Processing is triggered on page load, but xsl:template instructions may also be bound to DOM events so - theoretically - Silverlight could initiate an XSLT transform by triggering a DOM event.